# How can i fix the error POST http://localhost:3000/users.json 404 (Not Found) on reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

Basically i have a json file named users.json. (It is on public folder)

```
[{
    "username": "Antonio",
    "bestscore": "100"
},
{
    "username": "Tomé",
    "bestscore": "200"
}
]
```

And i want to add new users on that json file with two variables: username and bestscore

I'm doing a memory game that when user enter the initial page write his username. After user enter his username, i wanted to add his username to the json file, giving him as default bestscore:0.
Here is my code of the initial page:

```
class App extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     page: "game",
     showInicio: false,
     userInput:"",
     userInfo:[]
   };

   this.changePage = this.changePage.bind(this);

   this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
   this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
 }

 changePage(page) {
   this.getUserInfo()
   this.setState({
     page
   });
 }

 handleChange(event) {
   this.setState({userInput: event.target.value});
 }

 handleSubmit(event) {
   alert('Username was submitted: ' + this.state.userInput);
   event.preventDefault();
   this.setState({  
     showInicio: !this.state.showInicio 
}); 
   this.postUserInfo()
 }

 postUserInfo(){
 fetch("users.json", {
 method: "post",
 headers: {
   'Accept': 'application/json',
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 },
 //make sure to serialize your JSON body
 body: JSON.stringify({
   username: this.state.userInput,
   bestscore: 0
 })
})
.then( (res) => { 
  console.log(res)
});
}

 render() {

   if (this.state.showInicio === false){
   return (
     <div>
     <div className="inicio">  
       <h1> Memory game </h1> 
     </div>
     <div className="iniciodentro">
       <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
       <label>
         Enter your username:
       <input type="text" value={this.state.userInput} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
       </label>
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
     </form>
     </div> 
     </div>
    );
   }else{
   const { page } = this.state;
   return (
     <div className="App">
       <NavBar page={page} changePage={this.changePage} />
       <div className="App-header">
         {page === "game" && <Game username = {this.state.userInput}/>}
         {page === "leaderboard" && <LeaderBoard />}
       </div>
     </div>
   );
 }
}
}
export default App;
```

I'm getting this error: POST http://localhost:3000/users.json 404 (Not Found)

Anyone can help me?

Comment: How are you serving the users.json file? Usually you'll either have code that handles serving that file or wrap the request in an API endpoint but without more information it looks like you're trying to just reference a file on your system.

Comment: I'm newbie on this so i couldn't understand your question. But I already did acess the json file when i wrote a  get fetch, and that worked. I got all the data from the json file. But when doing a post, i got this error. Do i have to write any code in order to perform a post method?

Comment: Use this library to serve json [http-server](https://github.com/http-party/http-server)

Comment: Most likely. I don't think just having a file on a server (which is what you are simulating by running services locally via localhost bound to ports) support GET and POST requests. Is the intent to store the data file on the same device and/or service that runs your react app? Because if so you can look into webpack. If not, then I'd look into http-server or express for implementing an API to serve your data.

Comment: But i did a get request and it worked....

Comment: What are you using to run your react app? My suspicion is that you are requesting the document from the same service and that is configured to get files with GET requests but not POST requests.

Comment: node.js i guess... I'm using visual studio to write the code

Comment: What does the scripts section of your package.json look like?

Comment: like this: https://imgur.com/a/1hwjS5F

Comment: Ok. Right. So you're trying to update a file by just posting to it? If so, that's not going to work. I reread your question and for what you intend to do, I'd suggest using express (it has a generator and documentation) to generate an API, write a simple endpoint to take a user and a score and put it in a file, and post to that. You'll create the API project next to your current project and you'll run it at the same time but on a different port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it can't find it is because users.json is not being served up anywhere. It is simply a file. In order to use `fetch` it needs to be hitting some type of endpoint (endpoint is a location that is hosted on a server i.e. examplesite.com/aboutme --> about me is the endpoint hosted on the website examplesite.com).

You should either run a server using express that will allow you to host that file and utilize it like an API endpoint. Or, you can manually edit the file. React has a good library for this called [edit-json-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/edit-json-file). It seems pretty straight forward to use, you can edit the file locally, AND you don't have to create an API or additional server.

So, quick answer: if you're just worrying about editing the file, edit it manually rather than hosting it on a server. But, if you want that experience and want to learn how to host an API, use express and host it there. Then, fetch the endpoint and execute the POST request like you've done in your code.

Comment: That's exactly what I was getting at.